# A partir de tuplas2 , quitar los None y construir una tupla 2

Tags: scala

Saludos a todos. Estoy trabajando con tuplas2 como las siguientes (el patrón se presenta asi n veces):

```
(Some("algo"), None)
(None, Some("otro"))
```

Que forman parte de un RDD de spark llamado *brand* y me gustaría obtener una funcionalidad que quite los None y mantenga las tuplas2:
*(Some("algo"), None), (None, Some("otro")) => (Some("algo"), Some("otro"))*

Por ejemplo, hasta el momento he hecho lo siguiente (sin el resultado deseado):

```
val brand2 = brand.map{
  _ match {
      case a if(a._1.isInstanceOf[Some[String]]) => a._1
      case a if(a._2.isInstanceOf[Some[String]]) => a._2
      case _ => None
   }
}
```

De donde solo obtengo:

```
Some("algo")  
Some("otro")
```

Pero lo quisiera obtener como tupla2 y quitar los None:

```
(Some("algo"), Some("otro"))
```

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
val brand: Seq[(Option[String], Option[String])] =
  Seq((None, Some("algo")), (Some("otro"), None))

val result = for {
  val1 <- brand.map(_._1).find(_.isDefined)
  val2 <- brand.map(_._2).find(_.isDefined)
} yield (val1, val2)

result.getOrElse(throw new UnsupportedOperationException)
```

Creo que esto te lo podria resolver. En caso de que la lista contenga del lado A todo en None, arrojaria una UnsupportedOperationException